# How to make a restartable, thread-safe AfterFunc() call

Tags: go, concurrency

How can I make a delayed, restartable function call in a thread-safe fashion? It's a pretty common use case, for example, if you want to react to some changes, but not more often than once in X milliseconds.

The code I can come up with is:

```golang
var t *time.Timer
func restartableDelayed()  {
    if t != nil {
        t.Stop()
    }
    t = time.AfterFunc(time.Second, func() {
        t = nil
        // ...
        // Do the stuff here
        // ...
    })
}
```

The obvious problem here is that the `t = nil` assignment is called from another goroutine than the initial assignment, which is subject to racing.

How can this be done in a proper concurrency-safe way? The only thing I can think of here is involving a mutex to synchronise the access to `t`, but that feels a bit cumbersome. Are there any more concise options?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if it has been called before, but the timeout has not expired, and a new call is issued? Discard it? Queue it after the timeout?

Comment: yes, discard. Hence the `t.Stop()` call

Comment: You might find golang.org/x/time/rate and golang.org/x/sync/singleflight interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a mutex here is reasonable, can't think of a simpler solution.

You only need to add a few lines and it's ready to go:

```
var (
    mu sync.Mutex
    t  *time.Timer
)

func restartableDelayed() {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    if t != nil {
        t.Stop()
    }
    t = time.AfterFunc(time.Second, func() {
        mu.Lock()
        t = nil
        mu.Unlock()

        // Do the stuff here
    })
}
```